# How do I know when a water heater's relief valve should be replaced?

Tags: boiler

My relief valve has been leaking lately. It looks like its not working right. How do know when its not working right? Its leaking from the end of the pipe the spring seems like its not working right

[image]

Comment: you have to determine why it is leaking ..... you did not say where it is leaking .... it could be defective or it could be venting because of over-pressure

Comment: that information should be added to your question above .... please edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a "steam safety valve", the correct term for those used on a steam boiler, they should be replaced when they fail to open, can not be manually opened by the lever on top, or begin to leak as yours is doing. Steam systems should be inspected annually by a licensed HVAC company to be sure that they are safe to operate.  I am not sure how strict the code is for a residential boiler but for commercial and industrial boilers that I serviced strict procedures had to be followed. Since yours is leaking, it is time to have the safety valve replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the info I haven't done a service this year . I will let them know when they come and yes its a steam system.

Comment: When you call the service company give them the numbers on the safety valve and tell them to bring one with them. otherwise they will charge you for a second trip just to pickup and  replace the valve.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure relief valves (PRVs) on boilers, at least in my area, are usually 30psi. Normally systems run at about 20psi hot and are set to 12-15 psi cold. Your first step is to determine what your system pressure is supposed to be. Then determine what your system pressure is. If it all checks out you need to change your PRV. They often continue to drip after they start dripping due to sediment build up on the valve seat, so regardless you may need to change it anyway. 15psi PRVs are usually used on steam and you have to be very careful if you are indeed running a steam system as you could easily get burned.